# How does Tomcat define Contexts?

Tags: java, tomcat

The Tomcat [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) lists three places to define a Context:

- `/META-INF/context.xml`
- `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/filename.xml`
- `conf/server.xml`

However, I'm examining a functioning webapp where the webapp Context is defined explicitly in none of these places.  Are there other means of defining a Context?  For example, is the existence of a directory `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/anyNameHere/` alone sufficient to define a Context?

Tomcat 7.0 on Ubuntu 14, for reference.

**Edit:** The webapp also does not have a `WEB-INF/web.xml` file, but JSP files within the webapp's `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/anyNameHere/` directory are still served, indicating that Tomcat recognizes it as a defined Context.

In fact, if I *add* a blank `web.xml` file to the `WEB-INF/` directory, Tomcat instead returns a 404 when I access the same JSP files.

Comment: This will help you https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. A context descriptor is not mandatory. You can drop any directory into `webapps/name` as long as it has `WEB-INF/web.xml` and you are done.

Comment: I also don't have a `WEB-INF/web.xml` for the webapp, yet it's still served.  I'll edit my question with this.

Comment: @PiotrChernin Tomcat is using the default `web.xml`. If you add one, it has to be a valid one in terms of the DTD or schema for.